# How can I test whether UIElement is a Line or Ellipse?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I have several shapes Children at my Canvas. How can I test what Shpe is certain child of this Canvas? Whether certain child is a Line for example (or Ellipse, or Rectangle)? I mean what would be proper syntax to check this?

I.e. this syntax does not work.

if (myCanvas->Children->GetAt(i) == Windows::UI::Xaml::Shapes::Line) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

For example, something like this (see below) works, I just do not like it:

if (myCanvas->Children->GetAt(i)->GetType()->ToString() == "Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Line") { myTxt->Text = "anything"; }

Is there any other  "nicer" way to test it?